# Set minimum window size

Tags: vb.net

I have this code in form_load for setting minimum size of window.

```
Me.MinimumSize = New System.Drawing.Size(Me.Width, Me.Height)
```

I want to prevent user to minimize form more as It is when loaded, but It's not working. Do I have to set some other form property to make It work ?

Comment: `but It's not working` how do you encounter that? What size is the window set after your code snippet is executed?

Comment: I tested your code and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Maybe I told wrong...When I hit debug, form opens in some size. At this point I want to prevent user for minimizing form anymore - just maximizing  or minimizing to size which form opens.... See edited answer what else I have tried, in resize_Event.

Comment: What is `minimizing` and `maximizing` exactly for you? Do you mean the user pulling with holding the left mouse at the edge of the form or do you mean a click on the underscore `_` (minimize) or rectangle (maximize) symbol in the form´s upper bar?

Comment: I knew I asked wrong...User pulling with holding the left mouse at edges, I want this.

Comment: I´m sorry. I copied and pasted your code into my project and it worked perfectly. The form opened with size x,y in debugging and I was not able to resize the form any smaller than x,y. What else do you want or am I missing something?

Comment: Then why isn't working for me, do you have any special properties set up for your form ? Is It set to Sizable right ?

Comment: You're right, tried in new project and It works. But not on my project, damn.

Comment: Make sure from configuration manager that your project is building when you run it. Do a Clean and Rebuild and try again.

Comment: Check the `Form.Designer.vb` generated file. Maybe there are events declared which you might forgot to disable. Also check if the designer set some undesired properties.

Comment: Thanks Esko, It worked ! However I'll try your suggestion too Alex, I'll double check before proceding further. Thanks to both !!

Answer (score 0):

Code works, It was just some bug in my project which I resolved by rebuilding.